# How do I handle freeing unmanaged structures on application close?

Tags: c#, unmanaged, structure

I have a C# project in which i use several unmanaged C++ functions.
More so, I also have static IntPtr that I use as parameters for those functions. I know that whenever I use them, I should implement IDisposable in that class and use a destructor to invoke the Dispose method, where I free the used IntPtr, as is said in the MSDN page.

```
public void Dispose()
{
    Dispose(true);
    GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}

private void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    // Check to see if Dispose has already been called.
    if (!this.disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            component.Dispose();
        }

        CloseHandle(m_InstanceHandle);
        m_InstanceHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

        disposed = true;

    }
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("Kernel32")]
private extern static Boolean CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);
```

However, when I terminate the application, I'm still left with a hanging process in TaskManager. I believe that it must be related to the used of the MarshalAs instruction in my structures:

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
 public struct SipxAudioCodec
 {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
        public string CodecName;
        public SipxAudioBandwidth Bandwidth;
        public int PayloadType;
 }
```

When I create such a structure should I also be careful to free the space it allocs using a destructor?

```
 [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
 public struct SipxAudioCodec
 {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=32)]
        public string CodecName;
        public SipxAudioBandwidth Bandwidth;
        public int PayloadType;

        ~SipxAudioCodec()
        {
            Marshal.FreeGlobal(something...);
        }
 }
```

Comment: Are your sure your Dispose method is actually being called when the application closes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way to handle `IntPtr`-style handles in p/Invoke interop is:

- Define a class `SafeMyHandle` derived from `SafeHandle`. It should only override `IsInvalid` and `ReleaseHandle`, and do nothing else.
- Define another class `MyHandle` that has methods for the public API for that handle.
- `MyHandle` should have a private member of type `SafeMyHandle`.
- `MyHandle` should implement `IDisposable`, and its `Dispose` method should just call `SafeMyHandle.Dispose`.
- All of the p/Invoke methods should not use `IntPtr` directly; rather, they should pass and return instances of `SafeMyHandle`. The one exception is the "freeing function" that is called from `SafeMyHandle.ReleaseHandle`; it should take an `IntPtr`.

If you follow these conventions, your handles will be freed even if your AppDomain is rudely torn down.

Answer (score 0):

I have had cases in the past where the application hangs after closing, usually because not all threads were terminated. How do you terminate your app? Maybe threads are the cause?